# Why is PowerShell DSC saying I have a duplicate resource identifier when they are in different nodes?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to do something relatively simple in PowerShell DSC. I want to ensure that the same file is on two servers:

configuration.ps1:

```
Configuration MyConfig {
    # I want this block to be common to both nodes
    Node $AllNodes {
        File DirectoryCopy {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "File"
            Recurse = $true
            SourcePath = ".\example.txt"
            DestinationPath = "%userprofile%\example.txt"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = Get-Credential
        }
    }
}

Agents -ConfigurationData .\data.psd1
```

data.psd1:

```
@{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = "server1"
            Role = "ExampleRole1NotUsedYet"
        },
        @{
            NodeName = "server2"
            Role = "ExampleRole2NotUsedYet"
        }
    )
}
```

This doesn't work, and produces errors:

> PSDesiredStateConfiguration\File : A duplicate resource identifier
>   '[File]DirectoryCopy' was found while processing the specification for
>   node 'System.Collections.Hashtable'. Change the name of this resource
>   so that it is unique within the node specification.

I think there's some basic concept about PowerShell DSC that I'm missing out on. Is there a way for me to apply this file to both nodes? Ideally, I'd like to apply some resources globally, and then apply some to just dev/prod systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$AllNodes` is an array containing `[hashtable]`s, so when you use it directly, it's being enumerated, and then each element (a `[hashtable]`) when referenced as a node name is being converted to a string, which is to just going to display the class name; that's why the error says your node is called `System.Collections.Hashtable` instead of a name you expect.

Since both hashtables will end up being the same string (regardless of their contents), you are trying to create 2 `File` resources with the same name for the same node, which won't work.

What you want is to reference the elements of each hashtable, in this case the `NodeName`:

```
Configuration MyConfig {
    # I want this block to be common to both nodes
    Node $AllNodes.NodeName {
        File DirectoryCopy {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "File"
            Recurse = $true
            SourcePath = ".\example.txt"
            DestinationPath = "%userprofile%\example.txt"
            PsDscRunAsCredential = Get-Credential
        }
    }
}
```